# How do I know that cudaMemcpyAsync is done reading host memory?

Tags: cuda

For example... Here's what I see in NVIDIA's docs:

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, 0);
kernel<<<grid, block>>>(a_d);
cpuFunction();
```

Let's say this is wrapped in a function...

```
void consume() {
  cudaMemcpyAsync(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, 0);
  kernel<<<grid, block>>>(a_d);
}
```

What if I also have a function

```
void produce() {
  // do stuff
  a_h[0] = 1;
  a_h[1] = 3;
  a_h[2] = 5;
  //...
}
```

If I call:

```
produce();
consume();
produce(); // problem??
```

The second produce() will start to change the memory on the host at `a_h`

How do I know that CUDA isn't still reading the host memory during the asynchronous memory copy routine?

How can I safely write to the host `a_h` memory without disrupting that asynchronous mem copy?

EDIT---

I know I can call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `cudaStreamSynchronize()` but that will also wait for `kernel` to complete. I would prefer to not wait until `kernel` is done.

I want to start writing to host `a_h` as soon as possible, while not waiting for `kernel` to finish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a stream for the `cudaMemcpyAsync` call, you can insert an event into the stream after the asynchronous transfer and then use [`cudaEventSynchronize`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1g949aa42b30ae9e622f6ba0787129ff22) to synchronize on that event. This guarantees that the copy has finished, but doesn't rely on the device being idle or the stream being empty.